# mixins in Vue 2 vs composables in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, mixins, composable

I am building a Vue 3 project based on existing Vue 2 project and I am new to Vue 3.
In old project, data is shared between mixins and components so that I don't have to pass them from components to mixins or between mixins themselves
But in my new Vue 3 project, I have to pass data from component as parameters to functions in composables. Here is a example:

```
// Home.vue
import { transformData } from './transformer'
const listServiceGroup = ref({})
result = transformData(listServiceGroup)
```

Here is the problem: I have so many ref and reactive in my Home.vue component. I have to pass many of them into a function from composables as parameters, then pass deeper into other composable files.

I feel like I am not taking advantages of composables in Vue 3 at all. Please help and suggest me some better way to solve my problems

Comment: Maybe it's what you need https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject

Comment: This may be the case for global store, which doesn't need to be a composable in its simple form, https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api